# change value of parameters of a function within the function python

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, parameter-passing

I would like to define my function **f(x,a)** in which the value of '**a**' changes, so that every time I call **f(x,a)**, the value of '**a**' will be different. So far the following code serve the purpose:

```
a=0
def f(x):
    global a
    a=a+1
    return a+x**2
```

In this case, everytime **f(x)** is called, the value of **a** is changed as well.
I am wondering if there are any other ways to realize the results? Thank you.

Comment: what is expected input and output for this function? Your problem statement is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of using a mutable default value (normally this is a gotcha that trips people up, I never thought I would use it on purpose):

```
def f(x, a={"value":0}):
    a["value"] += 1
    #Do other stuff
```

But since you are trying to encapsulate a piece of functionality with some data you would probably be better off creating a new class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    def f(self, x):
        self.a += 1
        return x + self.a

foo = Foo()
foo.f(0) # 1
foo.f(0) # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `a` to `f` each time you call it instead of using a as a global variable. Something like

```
def f(x, a):
    # your code
```

A full example

```
def f(x, a):
    a = a + 1
    return a + x ** 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 1
    a = 2
    print f(x, a)
    # output 4
```

Comment: if I do this, it will give me the following error:  "SyntaxError: name 'a' is local and global"

Comment: if you call the function multiple times, it alway gives you the output 4, while I want to have 4,5,6,7,8...

Comment: You need to update `a` and pass it to `f`. e.g. `a += 1`, then call `f(x, a)`. I would suggest you learn some basics about Python function.

Comment: @ zyxue: I need to let the function f update the value  of 'a' everytime I call it, not by user. It is the whole point of the question... never mind...